# How long will realtime sessions stay active after disconnect?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I try to close the realtime document properly when the user closes the browser window.
But nevertheless the collaborators that closed the document still appear in the realtime model. 
For how long will disconnected sessions remain in the realtime model until they get cleaned up?
I've some of them in there for several days.

Comment: Are you seeing them in the list of GetCollaborators?  Or somewhere in the data model?

Comment: I'm seeing them in the list of GetCollaborators

Comment: As an example: I'm in the list of collaborators 4 times since days in the file with id=0B0oWsMDAc_SiaGwyWEZJdVRISlU

Comment: The collaborators should go away as soon as you close the document/tab, without you doing anything.  What browser are you using? Different browsers have different levels of reliability in terms of performing actions on shutdown, but any stale collaborators should also get cleaned up in a regular basis (O(hours)).

Comment: I've been using Chrome. The collaborators are still in there (since many days). Users of Editey are reporting the same issue.
As there is no way to clean up the collaborators manually I'd say this is a bug in the realtime sdk...

Comment: We have not been able to reproduce this issue.  Closing the tab causes the leave event to be fired, and the collaborator goes a way.  Do you have a specific example demonstrating when you are seeing the error?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it seems to work 99% of the times. I'll share a document with you with sticky collaborators in the realtime model.
You'll need Editey to open the document.
It is the document with the ID provided above - do you have a chance to debug the realtime model with the given ID at your end?

Comment: Can you send me your email (or a test account) so that I can share the affected document with you? My email is daniel.florey at gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recently pushed an update that should fix this issue. Collaborators should go away immediately if the page is closed normally and within 15 minutes in the event of a network failure or browser crash.

Comment: Cool! It seems already to be fixed for my sticky demo document :-)